# select rows in mysql with latest date for each quiz_id repeated multiple times

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table where each quiz ID is repeated multiple times. there is a date in front of each quiz id in each row. I want to select entire row for each quiz ID where date is latest with user. The date format is mm/dd/YYYY.

**Sample -**

```
USER_ID  Quiz_id   Name     Date        Marks    ..    ..  ..   
1           2      poly     4/3/2020     27
1           2      poly     4/3/2019     98
1           4      moro     4/3/2020     09
2           5      cat      4/12/2015    87
2           4      moro     4/3/2009     56
2           6      PP       4/3/2011     76
3           2      poly     4/3/2020     12
3           2      poly     5/3/2020     09
3           7      dog      4/3/2011     23
```

I want result look like this:**Result**

```
USER_ID  Quiz_id   Name     Date        Marks    ..    ..  ..   
1           2      poly     4/3/2020     27
1           4      moro     4/3/2020     09
2           5      cat      4/12/2015    87
2           4      moro     4/3/2009     56
2           6      PP       4/3/2011     76
3           2      poly     5/3/2020     09
3           7      dog      4/3/2011     23
```

Comment: Have you tried a query yet or searched this site already?  `The date format is YYYY/mm/dd` ... is the `Date` column an actual date type, or is it text?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes, it is working fine.

Comment: Glad it's all solved. For next time, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Your previous question was marked as a duplicate - did you try the link ? and if so why do you think it's not a duplicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use rank function to get the desired result:

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f05591f8b55252fbd74c5473713768c0)

```
SELECT A.* FROM (
SELECT A.*, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY USER_ID,QUIZ_ID, NAME ORDER BY DATE DESC) RN FROM
Table1 A ORDER BY USER_ID) A WHERE RN = 1 ORDER BY USER_ID, QUIZ_ID;
```

Comment: Kudos for the Demo link.  You converted the data when you entered it, so your answer is not technically correct but poster seems happy so who am I to say, right? :-)

Comment: Yes I converted it to Varchar because my intention was to solve the query and I hope poster understands that.

Comment: No worries.  In case others are reading this, my beef is that the Date value (first row) was given as 4/3/2020 but in your Demo you converted the input to '2020-04-03 00:00:00'.  This means the solution is to a different, yet similar, problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have MySQL installed so you will need to test and report back.  The general idea is to identify the row of interest using max and a group by (table t).  As the Date column appears to be text column (MySQL uses the format YYYY-MM-DD for dates) you will need to convert it to a date with str_to_date() so you can use the max() aggregate function. Finally, join with the original table (here table t2 to do the date conversion), as only the aggregate column(s) and columns named in the group by are well defined (in table t1), i.e.:

```
select USER_ID, Quiz_id, Date, Marks from (
    select USER_ID, Quiz_id, max(str_to_date(Date, '%m/%d/%Y')) as Date2 from quiz group by 1, 2
) as t natural join (
    select *, str_to_date(Date, '%m/%d/%Y') Date2 from Quiz
) as t2;
```

I don't recall off-hand but Date might be reserved word, in which case you will need to quote the column name, or ideally rename said column to use a better name.

Also, the original table is not in 3rd normal form as Quiz_id depends on Name.  Quiz_id, as implied, should be a foreign key to a lookup table that holds the Name.